# Importing Selenium2Library

Tags: python, django, robotframework, selenium2library

Have got stuck importing Selenium2Library for Robotframework.

When trying to validate my installation of Selenium2Library I get the following error in the Python shell

```
>>> import Selenium2Library
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import Selenium2Library
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\robotframework_selenium2library-1.7.4-py3.5-win32.egg\Selenium2Library\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keywords import *
ImportError: No module named 'keywords'
>>>
```

I had this error before with a different module and was able to fix it using easy_install (module name) however doing this for keywords gives this result

```
Searching for keywords
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/keywords/
Couldn't find index page for 'keywords' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
No local packages or download links found for keywords
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('keywords')
```

Any advice greatly appreciated as I'm not really a programmer but a tester. 
Thanks

Comment: Did ya install it using pip?

Comment: Yep installed using Pip.

Comment: gives response    Requirement already up-to-date: robotframework in    c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages

Comment: This might help - https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/robotframework-users/SizQ-Xzz9B0

Answer (score 1):

There is a pre-release package, which works fine with Python 3.4, [here](https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/robotframework-selenium2library/releases/) that you may install with:

```
pip install --pre -U https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/robotframework-selenium2library/archive/v1.8.0b3.tar.gz
```

The [Pull Request](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/pull/564) is waiting for merge.

Comment: I was able to update to robotframework 3, python 3 and the above Selenium2Library. Ensure it is the version `v1.8.0b3.tar.gz` not the `...0b1` version that is around on the net.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Selenium2Library is not compatible with Python 3.5. Please use Python 2.7 instead.

[Issue for adding Python 3 support](https://github.com/robotframework/Selenium2Library/issues/479)